# `this` coercion for method calls

Tags: typescript

I have a simple class `A` with a corresponding instance of `A` named `a`. The only method has a rather strict requirement for the scope for `this` (the `this` scope of `A`). All this class really does is print out the data it stores for this test.

```
class A {
    private _data: string;

    constructor(data: string) {
        this._data = data;
    }

    method(this: this): void {
        console.log(this._data);
    }
}

const a = new A("my_test");

function test_a(a: A): void {
    a.method();
}

function test_b(f: () => void): void {
    f();
}

function test_c(f: (this: void) => void): void {
    f();
}

test_a(a);                // [1] Perfectly fine
test_b(a.method);         // [2] Not fine! Runs assuming `this` was bound to `a`'s this
test_b(a.method.bind(a)); // [3] Perfectly fine
test_c(a.method);         // [4] Perfectly fine. Provides an error properly, but rather verbose
test_c(a.method.bind(a)); // [5] Perfectly fine. #4, but using bind properly
```

This test was designed to find configuration where #2 would cause a compile time error for improperly scoped `this` calls. However, it does not. To the best of my knowledge, `test_b` assumes `this: any`. And line marked #2, according to that logic, would implicitly typecast the method `(this: this)=>void` to `(this: any)=>void` without raising a compile time error.

`test_c` was the only mechanism I could find that would properly enforce `this` to be bound before being passed in as an argument.

I do not really mind that `()=>void` assumes `this` to be of `any` type. However, I do not like how `a.method` can be implicitly typecast to be of type `(this: any)=>void`. To me, this rather skirts around a rather crucial type checking mechanism. The alternative is to explicitly specify for every function and method that takes in a callable and specify their own type for `this`. Practically, this does not make sense as it relies on every method, self-written code and all library implementations, to explicitly define the scoping of `this` on each callback.

Is there a `tsconfig.json` setting to prevent this sort of type coercion?

Is there better method other than "just don't do that" to ensure type safety of `this` to be scoped appropriately?

Comment: Number 2 is correct. You declared `a.method` as though it has a context of `a`. The compiler is currently taking your word for it. You explicitly declared the context of method to be `this`. If you try `a.method.bind(b)` it will throw an error for test case 2

Comment: @apokryfos I declared `A.method` to require the context of `this` to be `this` (`A`), however, that does not specify that it has it properly scoped as you suggested. And nor did I explicitly declare `this` to be scoped accordingly for number 2. #3 illustrates the `a.method.bind(b)` case, which does not throw a compile time error, nor a runtime error.

Comment: `a.method.bind(b)` is not the same as `a.method.bind(a)` in the former case the context is bound to `b` which is (in this case) undefined and not the correct context specified in the method. `a.method.bind(a)` binds the method to `a` which is an instance of the correct context. In this case the context does not specify a specific instance but a type. I would argue that [5] is incorrect here

Comment: @apokryfos Given that `b` is another instance of `A`, running `a.method.bind(b)` will not throw an error, compile time or runtime. Given that `a.method === b.method` (changing this goes beyond the scope of this question), the functionality would be similar to `b.method.bind(b)`. However, changing the line to something like `a.method.bind(document)` for instance does properly throw an exception. My main point for this question is catching cases where `a.method` is not bound and passed into a `()=>void` where the `this` context is `any`.

Comment: The method context hint is optional. Is that the problem? I don't think its possible to make it mandatory (i.e. something akin to no implicit any) because that would make lambda functions unusable (since they have no context).